# Excel V look up for multiple Values problem

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble with the following problem.
I have Part numbers from A4 to A810 and components from B4 to B810(the part numbers are 1 row but within the same part numbers there are many components.)

I have a list of all the components without duplicate in column F and how many times a component occur in column G.

I would like to know which part number has a specific component. I would like a list of part numbers for each component.

So far I have the following formula :

```
=INDEX($A$4:$A$1000, SMALL(IF($F$1=$B$4:$B$100, ROW($B$4:$B$100)-ROW($B$4)+1), ROW(1:1)))
```

However, I do get a value problem after the 7th row.

Is there another way to do this, maybe another formula?

Here is an example of the data showing on the first 2 columns:

[image: Here is an example of the data showing on the first 2 columns]

Comment: sample data? Will help to add some context to your problem and formula :)

Comment: Just added some sample data. Just to add, the number of components varies per part number.

Comment: is that a pivot table?  If so it would be better to refer to the original data.

Comment: It is not a pivot table, it just copied and pasted this way.

Comment: then you will want to normalize the data to have a value in every cell, so A6 and A7 would have the same value as A5.

Comment: But it should not matter as I just want this value on column A if it has a specific value in B, or what would you do after normalizing then?

Comment: If you are looking up `126220-0110` then it will return the value in `A7` which is blank.

Comment: My formula above works with the blanks in column A but stops working after the 7th value found. Any suggestions?

Comment: I figured it out thank you for the help though! I just needed to use CTR shift enter.

Comment: If your formula works then there is data in A7 that is formatted to be hidden.  By your picture if you were to look up `126220-0110` it would return the value in `A7` and by your picture that cell is blank.  Hence the confusion.  Glad you realized the mistake.  BTW if you have OFFICE 365 Excel: `=FILTER(A:A,B:B=$F$1)` will spill the whole list without the need for copy down.

Comment: I do not have 365 but I will keep this formula in mind later on. Thank you!